# Replace values with values from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

I'd like to update df2 with df1 values to create:

[image]

Code to generate example dataframes below:

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict = {'Customer': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Last Accessed': ['7/16/2020','7/5/2020', '7/1/2020']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict)

test_dict = {'Customer': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'Date Accessed': ['5/15/2020','5/15/2020', '5/15/2020', '5/15/2020', '5/15/2020', '5/15/2020']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `concat` then `drop_duplicates`

```
df = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'Last Accessed':'Date Accessed'}),df2]).drop_duplicates('Customer')
Out[81]: 
  Customer Date Accessed
0        A     7/16/2020
1        B      7/5/2020
2        C      7/1/2020
3        D     5/15/2020
4        E     5/15/2020
5        F     5/15/2020
```

Comment: Alternate: `df2.update(df1.rename(columns={'Last Accessed':'Date Accessed'}))`, +1

Comment: @Ch3steR Just a small note, update will only work if indices of both the dataframe matches ;)..

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes true good point, may be we can set `Customer` as index then update and reset index. Like your approach, +1.

Comment: @Ch3steR Why not undelete your solution, you had posted earlier.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I didn't get a notification that you tagged me to undelete, did it now. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge` + `fillna`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on='Customer', how='left')
df['Date Accessed'] = df.pop('Last Accessed').fillna(d['Date Accessed'])
```

Result:

```
  Customer Date Accessed
0        A     7/16/2020
1        B      7/5/2020
2        C      7/1/2020
3        D     5/15/2020
4        E     5/15/2020
5        F     5/15/2020
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combine_first` after `rename` column.

```
df1.rename(columns={'Last Accessed':'Date Accessed'}).combine_first(df2)
```

Output:

```
  Customer Date Accessed
0        A     7/16/2020
1        B      7/5/2020
2        C      7/1/2020
3        D     5/15/2020
4        E     5/15/2020
5        F     5/15/2020
```